# Удаление файла из списка выбранных при загрузке

Tags: javascript

На кнопку загрузки файлов выбираются несколько файлов и выводятся их имена и строка `Delete` напротив имени. Нужно при нажатии на Delete удалять файл из списка выбранных.

Пытаюсь решить так:

```js
var upload = document.getElementById("upload");
var uploaded = document.getElementById("fileformlabel");

function getFileNames() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(upload.files, function (file) {
        return file.name;
    });
}
upload.addEventListener("change", function () {
    var fileNames = getFileNames();
    uploaded.innerHTML = fileNames.join('<span class="del">Delete</span><br/>');


})
uploaded.innerHTML.find('Delete').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    thisInput.remove();
});
```

```css
.del {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" multiple />
<div id="fileformlabel"></div>
```

([Ссылка на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39150rp9/5/))

Делаю на основе этого кода

```
if ($('.js-FileUpload').length) {
    $('.js-FileUpload').each(function () {
        var input = $(this).find('input:file'),
            list = $(this).find('.js-FileUploadList'),
            tmpInput; input.change(function (e) {
            fileobject=e.target.files;
            if (fileobject[0].size<=2097152){
                var thisInput = $(this);Icon js-FileUploadRemove
               thisInput.hide().before(tmpInput.clone(true));
                var fileName = $(this).val();
                fileName.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
                list.append('<li class="FieldFile__item">' + fileName + '<span class="Icon js-FileUploadRemove"></span></li>');
                list.find('.js-FileUploadRemove:last').click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    thisInput.remove();
                });
            } 
}
```

[Как вот здесь](http://www.office-planet.ru/services/furniture/)

Comment: В вашей песочнице не появляются кнопки на удаление. Да и несколько файлов выбрать нельзя :Р

Comment: А нельзя проверить `upload.files` и удалить из массива тот элемент, который совпадает с соответствующим `$(this);`?

Comment: @Visman всё нормально появляется

Comment: У вас Delete, это не кнопка. А просто текст, добавленный к имени файла. Он никак не связан с конкретным именем.

Comment: В вопросе и написано, что это строка, а не кнопка. Мне нужно именно при нажатии на строку удалять.

Comment: @cyadver а как их можно связать?

Comment: @Николай, на FireFox кроме имени файла ниже кнопки выбора нет ни чего. При выборе другого файла старое имя исчезает, новое появляется. Мультивыбора как и возможности удаления нет.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо, я проверю на FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, к сожалению никак.

Список файлов хранится в аттрибуте `files` типа `FileList`, а он помечен как `readonly`.

Вот здесь посмотрите:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file-interface
`readonly attribute FileList? files;`

---

В вашем случае можно попробывать хранить отдельно список "стертых" файлов и просто их прятать, не показывать. Но система их все равно будет хранить. И, когда в конце-концов форма будет отправлена, те "стертые" файлы все равно будут переданы.

Comment: У меня есть код который что-то подобное реализует. Я не до конца понимаю как приязать это к своему примеру:

Comment: Код и ссылку добавил, там реализуется как я хочу.

Comment: добавленный код неполон

Comment: извиняюсь, исправил!

Comment: @Николай, мне кажется, что в приведенном Вами коде делается не так. Там динамично создается скрытое поле и к нему привязывается файл. `thisInput.hide().before(tmpInput.clone(true));`. Ну и удаляется не исходный файл, а его созданный клон.

Comment: а для моего случая такое возможно сделать?

Comment: Ну наверное... Если на том сайте как-то сделано, значит как-то можно. Думаю, что Вам имеет смысл очень детально изучить их код и попробывать его переделать под свои нужды. Задействуйте developer tools Вашего браузера, отследите все события и динамичное создание элементов... Вобщем понять, как работает...